# How to constrain content inside a fixed-height frame using SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a view with a navigation bar, some other views with fixed height on the top and some other views with fixed height on the bottom (including a tab bar). What I'm trying to achieve is to constrain content to fix the remaining space in the center of the screen without using a scroll view.

The app needs to run on iPhone SE (1st generation) which is the model with the minimum available height. This content includes some multiline text and some buttons with multiline text labels so the idea is to scale the font and the buttons height.

I tried to compute the difference between the screen height and the top and bottom content, but some element (e.g. the padding) are dynamically computed by the system and I cannot assume to be fixed.

Here is the model of my view.

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        // Top content with fixed size
        VStack {
            Text("Here it's some multiline text")
            Button(action: { }, label { Text("Some other multiline text label") }
            // Other buttons
            Button(action: { }, label: { Text("Last multiline text label") }
        }
        /*
        What my frame height should be?
        .frame(height: ?)
        */
        // Bottom content with fixed size
    }
}
```

Comment: I think GeometryReader might be what you're looking for.  https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-provide-relative-sizes-using-geometryreader

Comment: You should not hardcode frame height. The provided code is not enough to replicate your layout, would you elaborate more?